# Функции объектов и применение стрелочных функций в Классах через prototype

Tags: javascript, dom

Мне нравится *JSX*... но так или иначе, после компиляции элементы *JSX* превращаются в объекты *JS*. Отсюда и родилась идея разминать свои пальцы и мозг в нативном *JS*, создавая для себя задачи, связанные с работой, к примеру, в *DOM*.

Эти занятия не имеют практического преимущества над уже существующими практиками. Скорее они направлены на укрепление знаний синтаксиса нативного *JS*.

Одна из таких задач - создание объекта, который имел бы ряд всевозможных методов для работы с *DOM*: построение и удаление тега, работа с *CSS* классами и многое другое, что может стать полезным. Всего лишь добавить новый метод в объект...

Сначала для создания объекта с методами я решил использовать просто функцию...
Конечно, функция еще "сырая" и имеет минимальный функционал: `placeIn(parent)` для внесения тега в *DOM* в определенного родителя, addClass(className) для внесения класса или классов *CSS*, а также `putText(Str)` для внесения текста в тег.

Я прошу опытных *"джедаев"* не сильно судить меня "зеленого", но всегда буду рад Вашим советам...

```
/**@description it comprises the methods of creating DOM elements;
 * @param {object} node which exists in DOM. Needs to be parent;
 * @return {object} with own methods and pars;
 * */
function initTag(node = "div") {
    if (typeof node !== "string") {
        throw new Error('the given node is not String');
    }
    const tag = document.createElement(node);

    return {
        tag,
        placeIn: (parent) => {
            if (parent.parentNode) {
                parent.appendChild(tag);
            } else throw new Error("given Parent is not in DOM");
        },
        addClass: (className) => {
            if (typeof className !== "string") {
                throw new Error('the given classname is not String');
            }
            if (~className.indexOf(' ')) {  //space inside
                (className.split(" ")).forEach((cls) => {
                    tag.classList.add(cls);
                })
            } else {
                tag.classList.add(className);
            }
        },
        putText: (value) => {
            tag.textContent = String(value);
        }
    };
}
```

Теперь инициируем три объекта, каждый со своим значением *"tag"*.
Далее мы добавляем классы и текстовый контент для *"детей"* родительского контейнера.
Причем, не важно поместим мы сразу *"детей"* в *"родителя"* или сначала дадим им классы *CSS* и текст. Главное, чтобы родитель был в *DOM*.

```
container.addClass("flex-box center");
    block_1.addClass("block");
    block_2.addClass("block");
    block_1.putText("block - 1");
    block_2.putText("block - 2");

    container.placeIn(plate);
    block_1.placeIn(container.tag);
    block_2.placeIn(container.tag);
```

Проблема началась, когда вместо обычной функции я решил использовать Классы, создающие экземпляры с прототипными функциями. А в прототипных функциях стал прописывать вот так:

```
function Tag(node="div") {
    if (typeof node !== "string") {
        throw new Error('the given node is not String');
    }
    this.nodeEl = document.createElement(node);
}

Tag.prototype.placeIn = (parent) => {
    if (parent && parent.parentNode) {
        parent.appendChild(this.nodeEl);
    } else throw new Error("given Parent Obj is not in DOM or not given");
};
```

и так далее....

В итоге,  я получал ругательства:  "given Parent Obj is not in DOM".

Все пересмотрел.... не могу понять, почему так происходит...

Answer (score 0):

Очень долго мучался, пока не понял, что стрелочная функция не имеет своего `this` и ищет утерянный `this.nodeEl` совсем не в контексте `this` экземпляра...

Итак:

```
Tag.prototype.placeIn = function(parent) {
    if (parent.parentNode) {
        parent.appendChild(this.nodeEl);
    } else throw new Error("given Parent Obj is not in DOM");
};
```

Теперь мы получили внутренний this и легко находим его.

Отсюда запомнилась важность `this` при поиске `this.nodeEl`, примененяя функцию через *prototype*, а также особенности применения стрелочных функций.